# jQuery UI Tabs - with one single container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

what i want is, something like that: http://css-tricks.com/examples/TabsNextPrev/ 
But in this example (or general by jQuery UI Tabs!) i have the same number tabs as of fragments (content div's). I would like the user clicking one number in the tab and after that below the tabs is only one! single div-container with an image. The image-link should generate with the clicked tab-number, f.e.:

Tab 2 clicked : http://www.abcdef.com/xxx/image_2.png 
Tab 11 clicked: http://www.abcdef.com/xxx/image_11.png

and the image in die the div container change according to the generated link.
Any ideas or working examples/fiddle's?

```
<div id="page-wrap">

    <div id="tabs">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#fragment-1">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-2">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-3">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-4">4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-5">5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-6">6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-7">7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-8">8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-9">9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-10">10</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-11">11</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-12">12</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-13">13</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-14">14</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-15">15</a></li>
       </ul>

        <div id="fragment-1" class="ui-tabs-panel">
               <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>  
        </div>

        <div id="fragment-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
                <p>Donec ultricies senectus tristique egestas vitae, et ac morbi habitant quam sit mi quam, malesuada leo. Vestibulum tempor Mauris tortor libero eget, egestas. eu vitae feugiat netus amet Pellentesque ante. amet, ultricies eleifend turpis sit placerat et semper. Aenean est. fames </p>
        </div>

        <div id="fragment-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
                <p>ante. Mauris Vestibulum est. fames egestas quam, leo. amet tristique sit libero egestas. ultricies mi turpis senectus Pellentesque habitant eu ac morbi netus eget, Aenean malesuada vitae, semper. eleifend et feugiat vitae amet, placerat Donec et tortor ultricies tempor quam sit </p>
        </div>

        <div id="fragment-4" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">

        </div>

        <div id="fragment-5" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">

        </div>

        <div id="fragment-6" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">

        </div>

        <div id="fragment-7" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">

        </div>

        <div id="fragment-8" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">

        </div>

        <div id="fragment-9" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">

        </div>

        <div id="fragment-10" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">

        </div>

        <div id="fragment-11" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">

        </div>

        <div id="fragment-12" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">

        </div>

        <div id="fragment-13" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">

        </div>

        <div id="fragment-14" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">

        </div>

        <div id="fragment-15" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
            <p>The end.</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Regards
John

Comment: Could you please provide some code for people for help? Thanks.

Comment: Also your hosted images aren't working

Comment: The link is only an example i found. I need something with images. I posted some code, which show that there are 15! divs for the content.

Comment: Hmm, maybe make a fiddle for us to see what the problem is.